# PHP set class property to retain its value on every call

Tags: php, oop, static

I know this is a simple question, sorry, but I'm still learning OOP concepts.

I'd like to have a class property that should retain its value during the execution and I need to get and set that value by different methods from within the same class.

My code:

```
class incarico extends globale { 
    static $contatore;

    // delete the product
    function delete(){

        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        // on every delete I need to get the total number of records
        if($result = $stmt->execute()){
            self::$contatore = $this->conn->query("select count(*) from ". $this->table_name)->fetchColumn();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function generaProtocollo () {
        // here I need the $contatore value
        error_log(self::$contatore);
        return $annocorrente . self::$contatore;
    }
}
```

When I delete the record with

```
$incarico = new incarico($db);
$incarico->delete()
```

The value $contatore is correctly set, when I (after) call:

```
$incarico = new incarico($db);
$incarico->protocollo = $incarico->generaProtocollo();
```

The value is empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: why you want this variable to be static? Also what is content of "globale" class?

Comment: I want it static because I need a sort of "incremental counter" to be stored and updated every time I delete records. "globale" class contains methods that I don't use in this case..

Comment: Why don't you want to use 1 object and normal method? Read about Dependency Injection, also your code is hard to read if you still learn I'd suggest reading PSR before you get bad habbits. `$stmt->execute()` does not mean that rows were deleted but that query was exectued, I think you look for rows affected which PDO rowCount() method gives

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I've read both Dependency Injection (quite understood) and PSR (need more study) articles and I whould do it like this: create a new $contatore class with a setter method which parameter is dependent from delete() method of incarico... is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class Incarico extends Globale 
{ 
    private $contatore;

    // delete the product
    public function delete()
    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function generaProtocollo ()
    {
        return $annocorrente . $this->contatore;
    }

    public function countRows()
    {
       return $this->contatore = $this->conn->query("select count(*) from ". $this->table_name)->fetchColumn();
    }
}
```

What you need to do is:

1. Write code in English it really helps and code is more readable.
2. Use PSR standards
3. You need to use the class not like Global don't think in global way, try to change your thinking to DI and object that has its state which is not global.
4. I didn't write it in the class but it's good habit to use getters and setters
5. I don't think that counting rows should be in method named delete. You should probably create the other method that count rows

usage:

```
$obj = new Incranico();
$obj->delete();
echo $obj->countRows();
$obj->delete();
echo $obj->countRows();
```

I don't really know what are your needs but also delete method could use param which is $id, it would be more clear that way.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your `$stmt->execute()` or `query()` returned false. Note that `$annocorrente` is also never set.